Odoo online requests not defined in actions
I have a very simple scheduled action I'd like to implement
webhook_url = 'https://xxxxx'

recs = model.search([("x_studio_processed", "=", False)])

for rec in recs:
    data = recs.x_studio_json_text    # json_text is just a text field with json in it.
    requests.post(webhook_url, data=data)

However I'm getting the following error, which didn't happen in the automated action version of this script.
RPC_ERROR
Odoo Server Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/tools/safe_eval.py", line 391, in safe_eval
return unsafe_eval(c, globals_dict, locals_dict)
File "ir.actions.server(1049,)", line 21, in <module>
NameError: name 'requests' is not defined

Is this a feature?  Is there a workaround?  I can think of one, but I'm new to Odoo and have no access to the code (I did mention this was Odoo online), and even this workaround is not guaranteed:
Basically, use the scheduled action to trigger an automated action (updating a field should do), and use the automated action script's request object.
Any thoughts or ideas?  I'm looking for simpler, Odoo-esque ways to handle this.
EDIT: I tweaked the description, because it turns out that both action types don't have requests defined.  I suspect that the requests that worked in an automated action were being done on an odoo.sh or homegrown odoo install.
So for Odoo online, even my workaround has failed.  My next try (a true work around :) ) is to use the external api to get these records, and then call whatever webservice I need.

Why not using an automated webhook action? It's just an automated action with another type of action in it (instead of python code): Send Webhook Notification. You can either try your workaround triggering that autom. action by a scheduled action or if possible just configure the autom. action as good as possible to just use it as be.

@CZoellner Good question - It's because you can't execute code on success or failure.  From what I see, you don't even know if there was a failure (the log calls switch doesn't seem to be on the "send webhook".   But another idea - if a webhook failure would stop further actions, I could create an action after the webhook action that would indicate success.  Any ideas about that?  (I'll try that now)

@CZoellner That did not work.  It executes the call webhook, without any kind of feedback, and then executes the next action.  However I hadn't gone down this path because of this "dead call" issue, but I should be able to call an odoo webhook to execute on a successful connection.   Pretty sure this should work, - if it does I'll create an answer for it (feel free to do so yourself and I can respond).

Because my answer is not about programming, i would like to NOT write an answer :D

@CZoellner Hah.  Suit yourself - Well deserved points :) for putting the idea out there, even if it requires some extra action to meet my requirements.

Round about solution:
Using a record to store the future request (the json to send to the server), the scheduled automation set's a field on that meta record to trigger a webhook.  I created a "spinner" - just increment it to trigger the webhook - it thus keeps track of number of attempts and makes testing super easy.
Nothing special about the webhook - it just calls the server with the payload in the meta record.
The script on the serverside returns back a success response asap.  This can be before storing or processing the data since this is not processed by a user script in Odoo.
Using PHP, call this function:
function end_connection()
{
        set_time_limit(0);

        session_write_close();
        fastcgi_finish_request();

        return;
}

While conceptually you don't have to do this, with Odoo you should because it has a pretty tight window for handling webhooks, and Re:my original problem, it doesn't allow you to interact with a failed or timed out request.
When you have enough information to let Odoo know of the results of the call, Call a webhook in odoo, making sure in the json response to specify the model and record id of the meta record:
$postdata = json_encode(["_model" => $jsonResponse->data['_model'], "_id" => $jsonResponse->data['_id']]);

On the odoo side, the webhook calls a set field action with the default record being the specified record - the is_processed field that the scheduled automation uses to filter for records already sent.  In my case this is sufficient since I just want to know that the information was saved into a db, which is a simple yes or no.  But feel free to process the "return" hook for more complex processing.  Keep in mind that responding to a webhook is also time bound without notification, so it's better to save the response and have a scheduled automation deal with the results.

As I can see on the error it says the requests library is not defined please make sure you import the library on the action you are using.
something like:
import requests

webhook_url = 'https://xxxxx'
...


Thanks Omar - However import is not allowed from "actions" - both scheduled and automated actions.

how about making the action execute a function and then the function should be defined inside a python file(model) and there you can import all the needed libraries.

I'm sure that's how people do their actions when they have access to the back end - either self hosted or Odoo.sh.  Unfortunately that isn't an option with Odoo online.  There may be a way to have Odoo create a mod specific to your company, but I don't know the full details.   Then you have to pay odoo both for implementation and to maintain  the mod.
